# Optimal allocation to different employer plans to reduce tax bill in current year

Tags: income-tax, canada, employee-stock-options, rrsp

I am a canadian citizen that work for a canadian employer and this is how my allocation to the various employer provided plans look. I read that I am required to pay taxes on the EPSP. Can someone suggest an alternative allocation to reduce my tax bill?[image]